# Building websites using JavaScript frameworks

Tags: javascript, web, frontend

I have learned and can read/write code in JavaScript. I am a backend engineer by profession and want to learn how to build websites. I have gone to the point where I can build wireframes and start writing basic HTML. I've never succeeded in creating a complete webpage, because they always looked awful midway through.

I've seen many JavaScript frameworks (like [Bootstrap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrap_%28front-end_framework%29), [Backbone.js](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backbone.js), and others) that one can use to create websites.

Which framework(s), if any, should I use? Which would you recommend I use to start building websites (and why, if applicable)?

Comment: The examples you give, (Bootstrap and Backbone) are frameworks for Javascript heavy frontend applications. They might help you with some realtime data exchange and form control mechanisms, but they won't help you build a site that looks any less awful halfway through. For that you need CSS and the assistance of a good UI designer.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't recommend you using a JavaScript-framework to build your entire website. I would only recommend JavaScript to enhance your website with cool features.

**I'm not sure what type of website we're talking about, but if you're planning on getting traffic from search engines — think twice.**

Google aren't that good at reading content embedded in JavaScript. Meaning: *your SEO will be terrible if you choose to build the website entirely in JavaScript*.

HTML/CSS is easy, man. I'm sure you'll be able to learn that in a one day — tops! You're a backend engineer by profession for gods sake, HTML can't possibly be that hard to get a grasp of :)

Comment: "HTML/CSS is easy" "learn that in one day". Get real. Please. Displaying content in HTML is "easy", writing semantically correct HTML is far from easy. Hacking CSS around to make it vaguely look like what you want is "easy". Writing CSS correctly that doesn't have browser hacks everywhere or looks filthy is far from easy.

Comment: I'm just trying to get this guy started.

Answer (score 0):

You can't exactly build a website using JavaScript. You could, but that would be very inefficient...I recommend going through some HTML tutorials, as you (and the websites you build in the future) will benefit a lot from the fact that you use HTML primarily, and enhance it with JavaScript. After all, JavaScript can't do much in comparison to HTML (since in order to build a site with JavaScript (or my interpretation of what that is), you need to have a basic understanding of HTML).

Unless I misunderstood your question, then that's about it. Frameworks like jQuery can really enhance a page and make it beautiful and, fortunately, much more user-friendly.

Comment: That is simply not entirely correct. ExtJS, for instance, has building entire web applications by using JavaScript as their core concept and use HTML as an entry point only. It works pretty well for them. I don't say that I agree with the approach - but it's certainly viable.

Comment: @ZenMaster: Well that's my point. I wouldn't "build a website" using Javascript. If the people you mentioned can do it successfully, good for them--but either way, it sounds like Javascript is simply enhancing their below basic HTML code.

Comment: not people, pretty successful JS framework. And no, it doesn't  - it creates the entire web application, HTML and all, in JavaScript. Look it up.

Comment: @ZenMaster: Looked it up, and my point is still valid in some cases--ExtJS pretty much works for more UI-oriented websites. I would still recommend that he, as someone who hasn't worked a lot with HTML and hasn't successfully designed a webpage, take some time to learn HTML, as that is the foundation of all web development.

Comment: No argument here. I was arguing your "it's enefficient" part.

Comment: @ZenMaster: Oh, I see...thanks for bringing that to my attention. I said because simply, in my experience, I've found it to be inefficient. One could rule in that he's using a framework that would do a lot of the work for him, and in that case, yes, it would be rather efficient. (Also thanks for showing me ExtJS. I'll be looking into that some more).

Answer (score 0):

You can't create a website (at least a dynamic one) without a server side language. There you can pull from a number of languages.

If you are just a JavaScript fan, then you can use server-side JavaScript code as Node.js. On the client side you can use jQuery and you can have a supporting database like MySQL.

Comment: As an aside: Don't use mysql with node.js

Answer (score 0):

I was in your exact shoes not so long ago - I'm a programmer and had no issues picking up the backend programming that is required of websites, but when designing the web page is something I just could not do. I would end up with terrible looking web pages which was very discouraging.
One great way to get around this is use HTML/CSS templates - there are plenty free ones available. Download one you like, then go through the CSS and change as much of it as you need to personalise your site. This process will also give you a great understanding of how CSS works, and how it should be used to design a page.
After doing this a couple of times, you will be confident/able enough to design a webpage from scratch. If not, continue using the templates. No harm in that.

As others have already mentioned, for a powerful, dynamic website you will need a server side language as well. Javascript frameworks like jQuery are nice for the front-end for the website. For the back-end you can try CakePHP, CodeIgniter etc., or just code the back-end from scratch. Doesn't seem that would be a problem for you.

Some sites that provide free HTML/CSS templates:

[CSS Creme](http://csscreme.com/freecsstemplates/)
[FreeTemplatesOnline](http://www.freetemplatesonline.com/)

Most of them are optimized for 1024x768 which might seem a little outdated for a few. Try tweaking the CSS code to make the template suitable for your purposes - change images, width etc.

Comment: xbonez: Could you provide the link of downloading the HTML/CSS template?